# ASP.NET MVC - Ignore specific route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to ignore routes matching this schema

```
/{controller}/edit/undefined
```

{controller} - could be any controller

BTW I was wondering when to use Ignore and when IgnoreRoute.

Comment: Who is sending such requests? A poorly coded javascript? Why do you need to ignore them? Why not fixing your code and stop sending such requests in the first place?

Comment: `undefined` is ...? any? js `undefined` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following at the beginning of your route definitions:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{controller}/edit/undefined");
```

> BTW I was wondering when to use Ignore and when IgnoreRoute.

It's the same thing. `IgnoreRoute` is an extension method that does the same as `Ignore`.